# How can I make an environment variable visible to a script placed in /etc/cron.daily?

Tags: bash, cron, shell-scripting, environment-variables, cron.daily

Say I have a script named "mydailyscript" containing the following:

`#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -z $MYDAILYLOG]; then
  exec 1>$MYDAILYLOG
fi
echo This script ran on $(date)`

and I then copy this script to /etc/cron.daily.

Where do I define the environment variable, MYDAILYLOG?
i.e. `MYDAILYLOG=/var/log/mydailylog`

Do I append a line to /etc/environment?

`sudo echo "MYDAILYLOG=/var/log/mydailylog" >> /etc/environment`

Comment: I tried appending to /etc/environment and got a "permission denied" error.env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a variable to for all users of your system, you add it in the /etc/environment. It is global environment file.

You want to define variable for your current script only, you can use the path as a regular variable before the place where you have used the variable or you want to add the path as a variable, you can  use export also.